# How to redirect all routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a working private-beta Rails app on mydomain.com. All the routes work.

However, I want to have a landing page on the root, and obscure all other routes. Users will not be able to go to any other pages without knowing a particular extension (for example, mysecretsubdomain.mydomain.com, or mydomain.com/mysecretsubdomain).

How should I do this without changing all the existing routes in my routes.rb?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `before_filter` in the application controller that checks for a particular parameter, and redirects if it's not correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please give a very quick example?